# Unable to connect to repository in repo-browser

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, windows-firewall

I have SVN server setup on Windows Server 2008. I access the repositories successfully from other systems. But recently I installed the TortoiseSVN (TSVN) on another server, Windows Server 2003, where I'm unable to access the repository.

I can access my repositories successfully from the web-browser. But not sure what is happening at TSVN repo-browser. It doesn't even prompt me for a username - password but directly displays the message that it is unable to connect to repository.

Could it be possible that my firewall doesn't allow this connection? How can i check it?

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web-browser can (under some conditions) show *root of repositories* and list all real repositories as subdirs, TSVN's repo-browser can't do it (now, before 1.8 release, where this feature was promised in Subversion, AFAICR).

You can:

- Use real URL of exising repository
- Check connection to remote repo from CLI (if you have command-line client installed with TortoiseSVN) `svn ls <URL-OF-REPO>`

Comment: Thank You Badger... I was using the URL as https://<server_name>/svn/
But Now i tries it with actual repository name https://<server_name>/svn/<repository_name>